# About disabling autocomplete in UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I long searched the internet and this site looking for a solution but nothing work. The problem is that in any registration form I make in Django, each time a user click on a username or password field, a list of previously entered values is shown and this behaviour is not desirable.

The raw fact is that, if I directly comment this line

```
widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
```

in

```
# UserCreationForm, auth/form
password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        #widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
```

everything work as I want including the username.

But I don't want to touch the Django UserCreationForm in auth/forms. The ideal would be subclass it, and customize it. Here what I did

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # prevents the form to automatically autofocus
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.pop("autofocus")
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.pop("autocomplete")
    #self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.pop("autocomplete")
    #self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete':'off', 'maxlength':'32'})
    ...
```

I tried it with many combinations, including with new-password, off, None, or even empty strings, everything is ignored.

I repeat, the only way to not autocomplete the username and password fields is to comment the widget line in the original class, but this would be a very bad idea and, especially, it would break every time I will upgrade Django.

Any other reasonable solutions?

Comment: Wait, but `new-password` is the desired autocomplete for `password1`, no? It doesn't show *old* values in most browsers, it proposes to create "new secure password" instead (Chrome and Firefox 100%, not sure about others). I'd say you need `autocomplete="new-password"` on both `password1` and `password2`, isn't it? Also for `username` setting `autocomplete="username"` is perfectly valid: your users often have beloved username and reuse it, it is absolutely fine to let browser suggest it. Or do your users re-register many times with different logins for some reason?

Comment: [documented here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-fe-autocomplete-new-password)

Answer (score 0):

I once had a registration form I wanted to get this same behaviour with... What worked for me was, for example:

`forms.py`

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
     username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={..., 'autocomplete': 'new-password'}))
     email= forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={..., 'autocomplete': 'new-password'}))
     password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={..., 'autocomplete': 'new-password'}))
     
     # Setting the autocomplete='off' from within the form class by using {'autocomplete': 'new-password'} to remove the suggested list over/below the input field
```

In your case, probably you could try...

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'new-password'})
          self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'new-password'})
          self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'new-password'})
```

Also note that you'd have to add `autocomplete="off"` on your `form` tag as well.

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

**Disclaimer**:
While the username and email fields aren't displaying the suggested list anymore, the password field continues for many persons. In my case it did, so as a work around I changed up some stuff to the following...

```
# Instead of a password field, I've changed it to a text field
# Setting onkeyup event that will replace the text to asterisks
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'password', 'autocomplete': 'new-password', 'onkeyup': 'hideCharacters()'}))
```

Within the `html` file:

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    ...
    ...
</form>

# This script can be within a javascript file or the html: up to you...
# Script to replace text from field to asterisk(s).
<script type="text/javascript">
     function hideCharacters() {
          var x = document.getElementById("password");
          x.value = x.value.replace(/./g, "*");
     }
</script>
```

In a nutshell, that did the job for me.